# why aren't these while if statements behaving how I want?

Tags: python

I'm learning python right now and I just wrote up this code for an assignment and it isn't behaving the way I expected or want it to.

```
while(number != 0):
def sumList(myList):
    myList.append(number)
    return myList
Sum = (Sum + number)
number = int(input("plese enter a number: "))
if(number == 0):
   def printList(myList):
   for number in myList:
        print(number, " + ")
    def main():
        myList = createList()
        sumList(myList)
        printList(myList)
    main()
    print(Sum, " ")
```

it should print out the sumList and the Sum when 0 is inputted but it's not and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = []
sum = 0

while(True):
    number = int(input("please enter a number: "))
    if (number != 0):
        sum = sum + number
        myList.append(number);
    else:
        for number in myList:
            print(number, " + ")
        print('equals', sum)
        break
```

Because yours had many errors, I rewrote it. Hangon I'll see if I can fix your version.

I still can't understand you code properly, but I've tried another version that's closer to your original, so hopefully you can understand better.

```
def appendToList(list, num):
    list.append(num)
    #return myList No need to return, I may be misunderstanding your intent

def printList(list):
   for num in myList:
        print(num, " + ")

def sumList(list):
    sum = 0
    for num in list:
        sum = sum + num
    return sum
#def main(): I don't know what you're trying to do here.
    # myList = createList() no such function exists

myList = [] # Create your list

while (True):
    number = int(input("please enter a number: "))
    if (number != 0):
        appendToList(myList, number)
    else:
        break

printList(myList)
print('equals', sumList(myList))
```

Though I think the first version is easier to understand. Also note that in Python the preferred convention is to use lower case separated by underscore if needed for function names. But I'm not used to that.